¿Por qué SQL Server Management Studio no me deja acceder a mis bases de datos?
Estoy dándole mantenimiento a una pc con el punto de venta MyBusiness Pos, y el error que aparece es "Existe un error al intentar hacer la conexión -2147467259..." en el que no puede acceder al archivo de la base datos. Vi que una solución era añadiéndolo con SQL Server Management Studio, pero la computadora Tiene Windows 7 y no me deja instalar la versión del 2005, instalé la versión de 2014 y ahora me aparece que no tengo los permisos para modificar ni añadir nada: "La Entidad de servidor "Fantastic" no puede tener acceso a la base de datos "model" en el contexto de seguridad actual.
Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 916".
¿Qué opciones tengo si no tengo permisos para darme permisos siquiera?
[Error que se muestra al intentar añadir una base de datos en SSMS 

De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda

El error en el software es bastante claro: El archivo LDF no está dónde espera encontrarlo el motor de DB. Esto puede deberse a que el archivo físicamente no existe, o bien a que el proceso del motor de DB no tiene acceso a él.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

El problema se describe en la ventana que muestras en la imagen:
La entidad de seguridad de servidor "%.*ls" no puede tener acceso a la base de datos "%.*ls" en el contexto de seguridad actual.
El problema es simplemente que no tienes permisos o el rol que tienes asignado no tiene los permisos necesarios para la base de datos, esta es la explicación:

El inicio de sesión no tiene los permisos suficientes para conectar a
la base de datos denominada. Los inicios de sesión que se puedan
conectar a esta instancia de SQL Server, pero que no tengan los
permisos correspondientes en una base de datos, reciben los permisos
del usuario guest. Se trata de una medida de seguridad para evitar que
los usuarios de una base de datos se conecten a otras en las que no
tienen privilegios. Este mensaje de error se puede producir cuando el
usuario guest no dispone del permiso CONNECT para la base de datos
denominada y no se ha establecido la propiedad TRUSTWORTHY. Este
mensaje de error se puede producir cuando el usuario guest no dispone
del permiso CONNECT para la base de datos denominada.

En este caso debes requerir al administrador que te asigne permisos para poder tener acceso a la base de datos requerida.

Gracias Jorge! Solo que la situación, es que es un equipo que me dieron a reparar. Digamos que se los vendieron ya "configurado" y no tenemos las credenciales. Crees que baste con desinstalar SQL y todas sus instancias y volverlas a instalar, o qué sería lo mejor?

En este caso, si se desinstala SQL, se eliminaría la base de datos también, tendría que crear la base de datos nuevamente y sus tablas. :-(
